# Remove event listener with an anonymous function with a local scope variable

Tags: javascript, dom-events

The `removeEventListener` will not work here because the functions are referring to an anonymous function:

```
const startSelectNode = (stepIndex) => {
  document.addEventListener("click", (e) => onClick(e, stepIndex), true);
};

const stopSelectNode = (stepIndex) => {
  document.removeEventListener("click", (e) => onClick(e, stepIndex), true);
};
```

But I can't name the function here because it requires `stepIndex` which is a local var. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yair Cohen's answer has the right idea, but it's missing something. `addEventListener` requires a function reference and not a function call. In his code, `onStepIndex` will get executed once and then never again.

To create a function reference *and* be able to feed it parameters *and* be able to remove the event listener later, you could use the concept called [currying](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-currying-in-javascript-ceb2188c339).

```
const onStepIndex = function(stepIndex) {
    return function actualOnStepIndex(event) {
        console.log(event);
        console.log(stepIndex);
    }
}
const handlers = [];

const startSelectNode = (stepIndex) => {
  document.addEventListener("click", handlers[stepIndex] = onStepIndex(stepIndex), true);
};

const stopSelectNode = (stepIndex) => {
  document.removeEventListener("click", handlers[stepIndex], true);
};

startSelectNode(1); // This adds the event listener  for stepIndex = 1
stopSelectNode(1); // This removes the event listener for stepIndex = 1
```

Basically, by calling `onStepIndex` you return the actual function, which is now the event handler. We saved the reference to the function in the `handlers` array and we need that reference if we later want to call `removeEventListener`.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely name the function, you just have to do it outside of the function's scope, like this:

```js
function onStepIndex(e, stepIndex) {
 // your action here
}

const startSelectNode = (stepIndex) => {
  document.addEventListener("click", onStepIndex(e, stepIndex), true);
};

const stopSelectNode = (stepIndex) => {
  document.removeEventListener("click", onStepIndex(e, stepIndex), true);
};
```

Comment: This is not how you pass a function reference of `onStepIndex`.